# Get String from JSON output

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

How to get .largeImage from

```
Game {
  name: 'Spotify',
  type: 2,
  url: null,
  details: 'Promises (with Sam Smith)',
  state: 'Calvin Harris; Sam Smith; Jessie Reyez',
  applicationID: null,
  timestamps:
   { start: 2019-01-25T19:58:17.089Z,
     end: 2019-01-25T20:01:50.398Z },
  party: { id: 'spotify:365162284655443978' },
  assets:
   RichPresenceAssets {
     largeText: 'Promises (with Sam Smith)',
     smallText: null,
     largeImage: 'spotify:b0875765de11e1b6bdfbdd07c2de72e65c02f524',
     smallImage: null },
  syncID: '5N5k9nd479b1xpDZ4usjrg',
  _flags: 48 }
RichPresenceAssets {
  largeText: 'Promises (with Sam Smith)',
  smallText: null,
  largeImage: 'spotify:b0875765de11e1b6bdfbdd07c2de72e65c02f524',
  smallImage: null }
```

I tried

```js
 Game.assets.RichPresenceAssets.largeImage
```

But that was `undefined`

So what to do now, I cannot find what to use, or what to do to make it propperly working.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Welp first issue, that isn't valid json

Comment: The JSON isn't formatted correctly in the post, does this match what you're actually running? *EDIT* You may want to try using jsonlint.com to validate your JSON as well.

Comment: Yeah it matches, but what is wrong about it?

Comment: @JespervanDaatselaar basic is right, you are missing `:` after RichPresenceAssets. And how you are not getting error after `Game { ... }` ?

Comment: Yeah I see, but that is exactly what comes out of 
```
message.mentions.members.first().presence.game
```

Comment: Well, i don't know really

Comment: As basic said that's not valid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
assets.largeImage
```

or

```
yourGameVariable.assets.largeImage
```

where you should replace `yourGameVariable` with the variable which contains the given dump.

It seems that you pasted a dump from dev-tools console. You can use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to get a valid JSON.

I suppose that `Game` and `RichPresenceAssets` are just class names.